# JScrollPane containing a JPanel won't scroll

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I have a JScrollPane which contains a JPanel which contains a collection of JPanels.

The collection size can be changed which is why I have it in a JScrollPane.

For some reason, no matter what I do, the knob won't show up on the scroller.

As you can see, the main JPanel (previews) does have a layout. I read that if the layout is null this might happen.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Keeping in mind that

- ReactionPreviewPanel extends JPanel.
- The show(ArrayList) method will create a bunch of ReactionPreviewPanels and organize them in the main (previews) JPanel using SpringLayout.

here's my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class ResultsPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1713825505191028954L;
    private JTextPane name, url, tags;
    private JButton clear;
    private JLabel results;
    private JScrollPane scroller;
    private JPanel previews;

    public ResultsPanel()
    {
        super();
        initElements();
        addElements();
        setLayout(getSpringLayout());
    }

    private void initElements()
    {
        this.previews = new JPanel();
        this.previews.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
        this.previews.setBackground(Color.white);
        this.scroller = new JScrollPane(this.previews, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        this.scroller.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(1);
        this.results = new JLabel("[Displaying nothing]");
        this.results.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        this.name = new JTextPane();
        this.name.setEditable(false);
        this.url = new JTextPane();
        this.url.setEditable(false);
        this.tags = new JTextPane();
        this.tags.setEditable(false);
        this.clear = new JButton("Clear");
        this.clear.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void addElements()
    {
        add(clear);
        add(this.results);
        add(this.scroller);
    }

    private SpringLayout getSpringLayout()
    {
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, this.clear, -5, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, this.clear, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, this.clear, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, this.results, 5, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, this.results, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, this.results, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, this.scroller, 2, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this.results);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, this.scroller, -5, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, this.scroller, 5, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, this.scroller, -2, SpringLayout.NORTH, this.clear);
        return layout;
    }

    public void show(ArrayList<Reaction> reactions)
    {
        this.results.setText(reactions.size() + " results");
        this.previews.removeAll();
        this.previews.repaint();
        if (reactions == null || reactions.size() == 0)
            return;
        ArrayList<ReactionPreviewPanel> panels = new ArrayList<ReactionPreviewPanel>();
        for (Reaction r : reactions)
        {
            ReactionPreviewPanel temp = new ReactionPreviewPanel(r);
            panels.add(temp);
        }
        for (ReactionPreviewPanel rpp : panels)
            this.previews.add(rpp);
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        for (int i = 0; i < panels.size(); i++)
        {
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, panels.get(i), 2, SpringLayout.WEST, this.previews);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, panels.get(i), -3, SpringLayout.EAST, this.previews);
            if (i == 0)
                layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panels.get(i), 2, SpringLayout.NORTH, this.previews);
            else
                layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, panels.get(i), 2, SpringLayout.SOUTH, panels.get(i - 1));
        }
        this.previews.setLayout(layout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, I'd guess that the container for your ResultsPanel is expanding to contain the whole ResultsPanel, so that the scroll bars are never necessary. Forcibly restrict the max size of the results panel and/or the container for the results panel.

Comment: I don't think any more details are necessary... The containing panel doesn't have anything to do with the size of the previews pane (which is bigger than the scrollpane).